# TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'" pandas

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am working on a project and so far my code looks like this:

```
def vacation_date(row):
if pd.isnull(row['vacation_date']) == False :
    return float((row['vacation_date'] - row['purchased_trip_date']).days)
else:
    pass 
preprocessed_data['vacation_date'] = data.apply(lambda row:
vacation_date(row), axis=1)
```

it is returning: TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 3')

I am not sure what I need to do to fix this, any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is `row` here? A dict?

Comment: `row` is going to be a Pandas series, I believe. It's coming from the data.apply() call

Comment: What on earth is `else: pass` for? It's completely redundant!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is one of the clearest I've ever seen in computing - it's telling you that you're trying to subtract a string from a Timestamp. Since what you're subtracting is `row['purchased_trip_date']`, it means this is a string. Convert it to another `Timestamp` first.

Comment: Awww... so happy AI exists now so that we don't have to deal with this passive aggressive bs anymore – "The error message is one of the clearest I've ever seen in computing"

Comment: @Dino I said it because it's true.

Answer (score 0):

how sure are you that every item in `data['purchased_trip_date']` and `data['vacation_date']` are properly formatted dates? I suspect that one or the  other is a string that can't be automagically transformed to a date. The error occurs when Python tries to subtract a timestamp from a string. You should validate the data in those two fields.